# Meaning of "labeling output" - exercise from "C Programming - A Modern Approach 2"

Tags: c, label

I'm practicing with this book "C programming - a modern approach 2" and the programming project 11 of chapter 8 says as follows:

> Modify Programming Project 4 from chapter 7 (I'm going to attach the
>   code below) so that the program **labels its output**:
>
> Enter phone number: 1-800-COL-LECT
>
> In numeric form: 1-800-265-5328
>
> The program will need to store the number (either in its original form
>   or in its numeric form) in an array of character until it can be
>   printed. You may assume that the phone number is no more than 15
>   characters long

The thing that i don't get is the meaning of the part in bold ("*so that the program **labels its output***"). What it means? I can understand English quite well but in this case I really don't get what the Author is talking about.

I already googled the meaning of "labeling" in CS and it talk about *goto* ect... This chapter is about **Arrays** so i guess the second part is important and is actually the answer and in fact is not a problem for me to modify the program as requested, I just would like to really understand the whole request and what I'm doing.

The code of the program to modify:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    printf("Enter phone number: ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {

        switch (ch) {
            case 'A': case 'a': case 'B': case 'b': case 'C': case 'c':
                printf("2");
                break;
            case 'D': case 'd': case 'E': case 'e': case 'F': case 'f':
                printf("3");
                break;
            case 'G': case 'g': case 'H': case 'h': case 'I': case 'i':
                printf("4");
                break;
            case 'J': case 'j': case 'K': case 'k': case 'L': case 'l':
                printf("5");
                break;
            case 'M': case 'm': case 'N': case 'n': case 'O': case 'o':
                printf("6");
                break;
            case 'P': case 'p': case 'R': case 'r': case 'S': case 's':
                printf("7");
                break;
            case 'T': case 't': case 'U': case 'u': case 'V': case 'v':
                printf("8");
                break;
            case 'W': case 'w': case 'X': case 'x': case 'Y': case 'y':
                printf("9");
                break;
            default:
                putchar(ch); 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you're missing two letters.

Comment: This is not a programming term. And likely not really a programming question.

Comment: The program shown in the question reads the input character by character and translates and prints the resulting characters immediately. The output is `1-800-265-5328`. The expected output is `In numeric form: 1-800-265-5328` and you are expected to store all resulting charactes in an array first, then print it together with the label `In numeric form: `. Note: As the task states a maximum length of 15 characters, I suggest to add one element for a terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: "Labelling output" will mean not only generating the number from the name, but using extra information to identify it — as your quote shows. It would be possible for the program not to include "In numeric form" but just print the number. The extra string labels the number and gives it context. In online quizzes, the judges don't want any extra information. In pipelines of commands on Unix, etc, not giving unwanted information is good (it simplifies the parsing of the data later in the pipeline). But for humans, and for later records, it helps to label what it is that the printing represents.

Comment: Couldn't I just print "In numeric form: " with a call of printf? I don't get the link between this and the Array thing.